# ruby Parent-Child recursion optimisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, recursion, parent-child

I currently have a rails app that has thousands of records linked in parent-child relationships.

I would like methods that returns all of the descendants or ancestors for each record in an efficient manner. I have a working method that does this recursively but it currently populates a large amount of arrays (up to 100k records) and then flattens these and removes duplicates. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this than my current code which takes hours to run for all records? I don't think that gems such as Ancestry are suitable because I do not have a strict tree structure.

Thanks very much in advance.

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :children, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :child
  has_many :parents, through: :relationships, source: :parent


  def all_children
    children.map do |child|
      [child] + child.all_children
    end.flatten.uniq
  end

  def all_parents
    parents.map do |parent|
      [parent] + parent.all_parents
    end.flatten.uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: `through:` doesn't look to me like classic parent-child hierarchy, is there a reason for that (makes recursion slower)?

Comment: I was thinking that this was an appropriate way to model a self referential relationship. My records are activities within a schedule which each link to other activities. Could you please let me know if there is a better way?

Comment: Guys, it looks like nested sets arent what I'm after because I my objects can have multiple parents. Therefore if anybody can provide a simple way to improve the performance of the code that I have it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you hcan have multiple parents, and multiple children, then it would be possible to have circular loops and your recursive code will break.   This describes a graph structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a slightly different way to represent the heirarchy in a nested set.   https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

This eliminates recursive queries.

Comment: DGM could you please tell me whether nested sets work when an item has multiple parents?  This is the case in my application, which is in contrast to all of the examples that I have seen.

Comment: Oh, nope, I missed that.   Nested sets is purely hierarchical.

Comment: If your queries always arrange themselves in terms of only following the parent relationships or only following the child relationships, I could envision a possibility of using nested sets with two different groups of pointers.   Call it A and B, so you would have fields:  a_rgt, a_lft, a_parent_id, b_rgt, b_lft, b_parent_id  ... I'm not sure if any existing gems support belonging to two different nested sets, so you may have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Using the most direct schema is pretty inefficient by its very nature. You might want to consider implementing the [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). A quick search shows there are several gems for Rails.